# How to design model that combines similar sources with different columns but keeps detail for PowerBI drillthrough?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am using PowerBI to report Budget/Actual information from different sources that allows the user to drill through and display related detail records. **How should data be modeled when "Actual" source tables share several common columns while having additional source-specific attributes the user wishes to see in the drill through?**

In the example below, data from 3 actual tables should be combined and compared against the budget for that same Date/BudgetID/TypeID. From the visual, the user needs to right-click and drill through to see detailed information that contains the source-specific columns. Is there a better solution than combining all actual data into a single massive table with null values in columns where the source doesn't have those specific field?  *(The the number of source-specific fields could be 10-20)*

[image]

Comment: This isn't really a question about drill-through but rather about data-shaping and modelling. Why are your 3 actuals tables different tables and not a single fact table? Are the additional attributes material? They look like they should be a single table to me. Is there any commonality between the additional fields - can they be normalised in some way?

Comment: Actuals1,2,3 are 3 raw source files of "actuals" at the same granularity (common columns) but with additional attributes pertinent to each source.  My question is how best to structure table(s) so actuals are combined and compared in total against budget (common columns) while allowing user to see source-specific attributes on drill thru.  I assumed a single fact table would be needed.  I considered a fact table of ONLY the common columns and throwing all other fields as a concatenated string in a single "extra data" column but thought there may be a better way.

Comment: I understand that drill-through prompted the question but this decision has wider impacts. Without knowing the detail, it seems to me that this should be a single fact table. You could have all the additional columns present in that table and just nulled out where they are not populated across all tables. I don't see any benefit in concatenating them but it depends what they contain and whether you'd need to sort or filter by the values present in them.

Comment: Agreed. I was uncertain how best to frame the question.  I have no need to use the data for sorting, filtering, etc.  It is merely a convenience for the end user to see the detail data in a tabular format.  The large concatenated field is not ideal but neither is having tons of columns with null fields.  Seems to be a result of trying to use an analytic tool to view transactional information.

Comment: Something I sometimes do is concatenate with line breaks or carriage returns so the concatenated data is still readable in rows but is really a single cell. You could even have label:value /cr label:value /cr label:value